# "Since time before..."?

Tags: grammaticality, phrase-requests

I'm trying to reduce the following sentence in size so it sounds more like a slogan: "We have been around before the [technology name] has become an industry standard".

Would it be correct if I spell it like "Since the time before [something]"? Also, what about pluralization? Like, "Since times before digital photography"? No?..

The catch is, I want it to play nicely with the visual identity of a brand, so what I'm basically looking for is a way of saying "Established [Year]", just a bit more wordy and fun. The name of said technology would be very specific and is expected to spark a bit of nostalgia in those who read it.

Thank you.

Comment: A slogan would be _We were around before `[technology name] `_.

Comment: Not gonna lie, that's kinda a lame slogan. The only way to describe yourself is in relation to something you didn't do?

Comment: The business that I'm working with is USA-based (it's a tech magazine, actually), and it's up to them to do all the work on text and stuff, I'm only in charge of graphics and software! So I basically needed a textual string that could serve as a placeholder for that specific area near the logo, because that's part of the design. Anyway, thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going for a slogan, maybe "Before [technology name], there was [your business]."

I think using a couple technologies gives it a little more power: "Before [technology 1], before [technology 2], there was [your business]."

If you want your original idea to sound a little better I would say: "We were around before [technology name] became an industry standard."

Or even "By the time [technology] came around, we already had 50 years in the business."